# Unusual spikes in CPU utilization in CentOS 6.6 while starting pycharm

Tags: centos, pycharm, cpu-usage, centos6

my system since last couple of days is behaving strangely. I am a regular user of pycharm software, and it used to work on my system very smoothly with no hiccups at all. But since last couple of days, whenever I start pycharm, my CPU utilization behaves strangly, like in the image: [Unusual CPU util](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PazEQ.png)
I am confused as when I go to processes or try ps/top in terminal, there are no process which is utilizing cpu more then 1 or 2%. So I am not sure where these resources are getting consumed.

By unusual CPU util I mean, That first CPU1 is getting used 100% for couple or so minutes, then CPU2. Which is, only one cpu's utilization goes to 100% for sometime followed by other's. This goes on for 10 to 20 minutes. then system comes back to normal.

P.S.: I don't think this problem is related to pycharm, as I face similar issues while doing other work also, just that I always face this with pycharm for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSSIBLE CAUSE: I suspect you have a thrashing problem. The CPU usage of your applications are low because none of them are actually getting much useful work done. All the processing is being taken up by moving memory pages to and from the disk. Your CPU usage probably settles down after a time because your application has entered a state where its memory working set has shrunk to a point where it all can be held in memory at one time.

This has probably happened because one of the apps on your machine is handling a larger data set than before, and so requires more addressable memory. Another possibility is that, for some reason, a lot more apps are running on your machine.

POTENTIAL SOLUTION: There are several ways you can address this. The simplest is to put more RAM on your machine. If this doesn't work or isn't possible, you'll have to figure out which app is the memory hog. You may simply have to work with smaller problems/data-sets or offload some of the apps onto a different box.

MIGRATING CPU LOAD: Operating systems will move tasks (user apps, kernel) around for many different reasons. The reasons can range anywhere from it being just plain random to certain apps having more of their addressable memory in one bank vs another. Given that you are probably doing a lot of thrashing, I'm not surprised that the processor your app is running is randomized over time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I couldn't understand how it could be thrashing, cos my memory utilization is 50 to 60 % (of 4GB memory).
Now it's also happening when I am trying to extract some tar files.

Comment: Take a look at any new security or accounting patches that might have been put into place. My company has recently gone on a security kick that is making some systems almost useless. Also take a look at any recent kernel updates.

Comment: After you mentioned it, I realized that this is happening since a new anti-spyware software is installed in our systems. I wonder if that's the problem. Cos it's getting to work in my system now. It takes around 10 minutes for my IDE to startup. Have you got any solution that I can try?

Comment: Most of these security products have the ability to temporarily disable certain features, such as virus scans, firewalls, etc. If you are on a Windows system, you can right click on the little icon in the status area of your task bar (assuming the IT department lets you). I haven't used virus SW on my Apple or Linux systems as I'm careful and haven't really needed such software.

Comment: I am using CentOS, and didn't actually needed any of such programs, but it was the company's policy. Well thank's any way.